# Sidekick 4g media volume doesn't save

Tags: volume-control

Just recently got myself a t mobile sidekick 4g. I am loving it so far except for a few quirks. This device doesn't seem to remeber what volume I set for media playback. Since I use my phone to play music or podcasts while I drive this means every time I get back into my car I half to turn the volume back up. Is there someway to make this setting behave like stock Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I am using [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&feature=search_result) to solve this problem. Just set headset plugged as the context, and make the task set media volume to where I want it. If someone finds a better solution and posts here I will accept it as answer.

Note The market version of Tasker was force closing on my Sidekick. I emailed the developer and he got it fixed. Look for apk version 1.1b4 or above and it should work on Sidekick. This update will get pushed to the market sometime I am sure (or maybe it already has been)